# Electrostatic effect on neutral papers by negatively charged comb

Tags: experimental-physics

I know paper changes its dipole molecules so the positively charged side will be exposed to a negative charged comb and then attracted.
But how do a paper piece’s molecules change, if paper is a solid?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I agree with community bot, it's difficult to understand what you are saying!

Comment: I have tried to standardize your grammar. If I have accidentally changed your question, please [edit] further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

“How do a paper piece’s molecules change, if paper is a solid?”

The paper's molecule DOES NOT CHANGE. Instead, the “electron cloud” is slightly shifted in the opposite direction of the comb. This indicates that due to repulsion, the electron in the molecule moves away from the comb. As the electron gets away, there is a charge separation in the piece of paper, and hence it gets attracted to the comb.